# Introjs in symfony page twig ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use intro.js with more than two pages in Html.Twig, is possible to use it in html.twig?

```
document.getElementById('#intro').onclick = function() {
    introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next page').start().oncomplete(function() {
        window.location.href = 'admin_administration_employees.html.twig?multipage=true';
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your twig file?

Comment: i wanted to understand why i can't use it to access for the next page ,

Comment: `document.getElementById('#intro')` is incorrect. You are mixing `jquery` with `vanilla javascript`. The correct code to target an id with vanilla is just `document.getElementById('intro')`

Comment: Thx for your help  :)